# Should ownership be ended before or after stl containers call its value's destructor?

Tags: c++, c++11

In the following code, an X is registered in a global container that becomes a shared owner of it. The destructor of X tests that it is no longer part of such ownership anymore, which I would expect to be a valid precondition for getting destroyed.

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

struct X {
    ~X();
};

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<X> > global_x_reg;

X::~X()
{
    for (auto iter = global_x_reg.begin(), end = global_x_reg.end(); iter != end; ++iter)
        if (iter->get() == this)
            throw "Oops. X gets destroyed while it is still owned!";
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    global_x_reg.push_back( std::shared_ptr<X>(new X) );
    global_x_reg.clear(); // calls X::~X().
}
```

When it runs (after compilation with VS2010), "Oops..." is thrown when the container is cleared.

Questions:

1. is this code legal? If not, why not? If so, should it throw?
2. should an std container implement `clear()` in such a way that during the destruction of its values, these values are no longer visible as containees.
3. should `std::shared_ptr::get`, when `std::shared_ptr` is destroying its pointee, return `nullptr`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per N3936 [basic.life]/1: "The lifetime of an object with non-trivial initialization ends when the destructor call starts.", and /3:

> The properties ascribed to objects throughout this International Standard apply for a given object only during its lifetime. [ *Note:* In particular, before the lifetime of an object starts and after its lifetime ends there are significant restrictions on the use of the object, as described below, in 12.6.2 and in 12.7. Also, the behavior of an object under construction and destruction might not be the same as the behavior of an object whose lifetime has started and not ended. 12.6.2 and 12.7 describe the behavior of objects during the construction and destruction phases. —*end note* ]

You are invoking a member function on a `shared_ptr` after the end of its lifetime. Since there's no way to know if a given standard library class member function complies with the restrictions specified, invoking a member function on a standard library object after the end of its lifetime consequently has undefined behavior unless otherwise specified.

See also [Library Working Group issue 2382 "Unclear order of container update versus object destruction on removing an object"](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2382), which pertains very much to the question. In general, it's not a good idea to re-enter a standard library object (`global_x_reg`) while it is in the middle of processing a member function call (`global_x_reg.clear()` in this case). The class invariants obviously must hold before and after a member call, but there is no guarantee that the object is in a valid state *during* a call.

Comment: I'm confused. How can a destructor do anything useful if the object's lifetime is over at the beginning of the call? If you can't call member functions on an object being destroyed then why can you access its data members?

Comment: @Simple It isn't forbidden in general to access an object after the end of its lifetime, although what you are allowed to do with such an object is very restricted. (See the references in the citation for [basic.life]/3 that I have placed entire in the answer.)

Comment: @Casey: Thanks, LWG issue 2382 gives an even better description of the situation that i faced. I understand now that code shouldn't re-enter std containers. The OP example was distilled from a real code situation with highly recursive data structures. Although I agree with the LWG poster Peter Kasting that it makes the most sense to say that  objects should be removed from the container before they are destroyed, I will remove asserts that this is a currently valid precondition, and try to avoid re-entrance.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's any particular reason that `.get()` *must* return `NULL` before the deleter (and, consequently, `~X()`) is invoked by `std::shared_ptr<X>::~shared_ptr<X>`. The only requirement is that it returns `NULL` once `std:shared_ptr<X>::~shared_ptr<X>` has completed.

Similarly, if `std::vector` is using placement new to construct and destroy its elements (and it will be), there's no reason that it *must* have updated its accessors before destroying a placed element.

In fact, if you think about this common old-fashioned pattern:

```
T* ptr = new T();
delete ptr;
ptr = NULL;
```

It's clear that `~T()` will be invoked before `ptr` is set to `NULL`; this is pretty much the same thing that you're seeing.

The following extract from libstdc++ v4.6.3 supports the analogy:

```
00353       virtual void
00354       _M_destroy() // nothrow
00355       {
00356     _My_alloc_type __a(_M_del);
00357     this->~_Sp_counted_deleter();
00358     __a.deallocate(this, 1);
00359       }
```

([link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/libstdc++/api/a01031_source.html#l00354))

In short, you're observing a totally harmless implementation detail and trying to assert that it breaks stated semantics, when I don't think that it does.

Comment: I think you’re addressing the wrong question here: OP isn’t asking why the *pointer* still owns the object – rather, why the *container* still contains the smart pointer at the time the constructor is called. This may be related (in a naive implementation, it’s definitely a consequence), but it’s sufficiently different.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: True; I meant to make the same argument for vector at the same time. Added that now. Matching snippet from libstdc++ incoming _[edit: nah, too complex]_

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing a strange thing here. If you want to keep access to your elements you should implement `X::~X()` in such a way that the destroyed object is unregistered but not clear the std::vector itself. Also, the shared pointer is invalidated (and X is destroyed) inside the call to `clear()` of the `std::vector` in question. Therefore the `std::vector` is in a fragile state and I would in any case not rely on it to much. Consider the example of a linked list: If you remove an item which is destroyed in the progress and the destructor iterates over the list it might be the case that the references to nodes are not in a consistent state. I would avoid this situation.